# How to move all files within a folder, but not the parent folder itself?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I'm trying to move all folders from my development environment (in a /dist folder) to the root of my production environment. Currently, when I select all the files and "copy to right", it moves the files and includes the parent folder (dist). Then I have to go through the process of pulling them out of that parent folder and place on the root.

How do I set this up to avoid that? I only want to move the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Beyond Compare, right click on the /dist folder and select **Set as Base Folder**. Copies are relative to the base folder (folder loaded using Browse button and shown in the path edit).

Comment: You would be the same 'Chris K' that answered my question in the scooter software forum. Thanks.